# Is it true that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1}f_n(x)\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx$ in general and if $|f_n(x)|\le 2017$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

Let $f_n(x)$ and $f(x)$ be continuous functions on $[0, 1]$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x) = f(x)$ for all $x \in [0, 1]$. Answer each of the following questions. If your answer is “yes”, then
provide an explanation. If your answer is “no”, then give a counterexample.

(a) Can we conclude that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1}f_n(x)\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx$?

(b) If in addition we assume $|{f_n(x)}|\leq 2017$ for all n and for all $x \in [0, 1]$, can we conclude that  $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1}f_n(x)\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx$?

My attempt:

I could not think of any counterexample for part (a).

For part (b), I showed that ${f_n}$ is equicontinuous which along with uniform boundedness gives me that ${f_n}$ has a uniformly convergent subsequence. (Arzela Ascoli). Hence $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1}f_n(x)\,dx= \lim_{k\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1}f_{n_k}(x)\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx$. Is that right?

Edit: I have made a mistake while proving equicontinuity.

I know that monotonicity + continuity + pointwise convergence on [0,1] ensures uniform convergence. Is it true that uniform boundedness + continuity + pointwise convergence ensures uniform convergence? How do I show that?

Comment: For part (a) see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2877869/how-to-construct-a-counterexample-to-lim-n-to-infty-int-01-f-nxdx-int-0/2877882#2877882

Comment: What you've done for part $(b)$ is not quite right.
You either need to show that all of $f_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly, or else that the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1}f_n(x)\,dx$ exists. If you don't know that the limit exists, it does not make sense to claim equality with the limit of a subsequence.

Comment: Actually it could be proved that if $f_n$ is equicontinuous and uniformly bounded then the convergence is uniform.

Comment: The hypothesis in part b) does not imply uniform convergence or equicontinuity. Example: $f_n(x)=nx$ for $0\leq x \leq \frac 1 n$, $f_n(x)=1-n(x-\frac  1 n)$ for $\frac 1 n\leq x \leq \frac 2 n$ .

Comment: @xbh Then Arzela Ascoli would guarantee uniform convergence of ${f_n}$, not just of a subsequence.

Comment: @Xplorer Here the function family is **countable**, and the interval is closed, you could try to prove this. Maybe the property of compact sets would help.

Comment: @xbh But Arzela Ascoli also holds for sequence of functions on compact sets. I probably did not understand you.

Comment: @Xplorer This question is a specific case for A-A theorem. The assumption is stronger than that of A-A: $f_n \to f$, which is not stated in A-A.

Comment: Also part b) is a simpler case for Arzela Dominated convergence theorem [whose proof is complicated]. As the comment by @K.R. Murthy shows, your method might need to be reconsidered.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks for your clarification!

Comment: By the way, how did you show that $f_n$ is equicontinuous?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri I realised I made a mistake while proving equicontinuity. I'll edit my question.

Comment: Yes, I think it's not true in general. Consider a tent sequence with fixed height, say $f_n(0) = 0$, then $f_n$ rises linearly to $1$ at $x=1/(2n)$, after which it goes back linearly to $0$ at $x=1/n$ and stays there.
This sequence converges pointwise to the everywhere-zero function.
The integrals do converge, but we don't have equicontinuity (inspect near $x=0$).
This is also obvious *a posteriori*, since clearly this sequence does not converge uniformly to zero.

Comment: Since you know that monotonicty + continuity + pointwise convergence implies uniform convergence on compacts, you have a particular case of the [monotone convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem). You can use it to prove (a particular case of) [Fatou's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma), which is all you really need to prove (a particular case of) the [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem). Not sure how all of this fits into a qualifying exam question, though.

Comment: This question was exactly the reason why I asked the question @JackyChong mentions. For part $(b)$, you can take a look at what is called Arzela's Dominated Convergence Theorem (also see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1779874/531299)

Comment: Oops, I haven't noticed that @xbh had already mentioned Arzela's DCT. (But you can find a link to its proof in the answer I referred to above.) Not sure if we're allowed to use this theorem though.

Answer (score 1):

The question of switching limits is an important one, and with the Lebesgue integral one gets the powerful dominated convergence theorem. However, I presume you are using the Riemann integral.

For part a), I will give you a place to start. We denote the function $ \chi_S : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ via

\begin{equation*}
   \chi_S(x) = \begin{cases} 
        1 & x \in S \\
        0 & x \notin S
   \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

For any subset $ S \subseteq \mathbb R $.

Let $ f_n = n \chi_{(0, \frac{1}{n})} $. Check that $ f_n(x) \to 0 $ for all $ x \in [0, 1] $, so $ f(x) = 0 $. Hint: do this first for $ x = 0 $, then for $ x \in (0, 1] $. It is easy to see that $ \int_{0}^{1} f_n(x) \,dx = 1 $ for all $ n $. Then $ f_n \to f $ pointwise, but $ \int_{0}^{1} f_n(x) \,dx \not\to 0 = \int_{0}^{1} f(x) \,dx $. These functions are not continuous, so I will leave it to you to modify these to get a continuous version of this counterexample. In fact, it is possible to find a counterexample where each function is smooth.

For part b), your proof is close, but you need more detail to fill it out. Specifically, you have shown that $ f_{n_k} $ converges uniformly to $ f $, but you have not shown this for $ f_n $. To do this, you must use the fact that $ f_n \to f $ pointwise, as this is false otherwise. Suppose then that $ f_n $ does not converge uniformly to $ f $. Then, there exists an $ \epsilon > 0 $ such that for some $ n_m \to \infty $, there exists a sequence $ x_{n_m} $ in $ [0, 1] $ such that $ |f_{n_m}(x_{n_m}) - f(x_{n_m})| \geq \epsilon $. We get this by negating the definition of uniform convergence. However, this tells us that no subsequence of $ f_{n_m} $ converges uniformly to $ f $, but Arzela Ascoli guarantees the existence of a uniformly convergent subsequence, and the pointwise convergence of $ f_n $ to $ f $ tells us that this uniformly convergent subsequence must converge to $ f $. This is a contradiction, so $ f_n \to f $ uniformly, so $ \int_0^1 f_n(x) \, dx \to \int_0^1 f(x) \, dx $.

Comment: How can it be done without assuming equicontinuity? (since the sequence need not be equicontinuous).

Comment: Are you allowed to use Lebesgue integration?

Comment: No, we aren't. This is a qualifying exam question.

Comment: I believe equicontinuity may be necessary, as it is not true that if $f_n\tof$ pointwise and some subsequence converges uniformly to $f$ that $f_n\tof$ uniformly. For example, take some sequence $f_n\tof$ pointwise but not uniformly. Then let $g_{2n} = f_n$, $g_{2n+1} = f$. Then $g_n\tof$ pointwise, $g_{2n+1}\tof$ uniformly, but $g_n\not\tof$ uniformly.

Comment: @Xplorer I would think if it's a qualifying exam question it would be *expected* that hte integral is in the Lebesgue sense

Comment: @qbert If it's an analysis qual I would agree, but if it's a general qual then I would stick to the Riemann integral, as not all undergrad curriculums cover measure theory.

Comment: @qbert It's not in the Lebesgue sense. Lebesgue integrals and/or measure theory are not in the syllabus.